# Do GPT-4 and GPT-3.5 share the same token encoder?

Tags: token, openai-api, gpt-3, gpt-4

I want to know if I can use the same token counter for various GPT models - especially GPT-3, GPT-3.5, and GPT-4.

GPT models by OpenAI need texts to be tokenized (using [Byte Pair Encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_pair_encoding), BPE), see [Interactive GPT tokenizer](https://platform.openai.com/tokenizer). I haven't found a direct statement if they use the same or different tokenizers. Even this official OpenAI page says that:

> If you need a programmatic interface for tokenizing text, check out our [tiktoken](https://github.com/openai/tiktoken) package for Python. For JavaScript, the [gpt-3-encoder](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gpt-3-encoder) package for node.js **works for most GPT-3 models**.

Answer (score 1):

Although I cannot find it in the official documentation, GPT-3.5 and GPT-4 seem to share `cl100k_base` encoding.

See e.g. [gpt-tokenizer](https://github.com/niieani/gpt-tokenizer).

> - `gpt-4-32k` (`cl100k_base`)
> - `gpt-4-0314` (`cl100k_base`)
> - `gpt-4-32k-0314` (`cl100k_base`)
> - `gpt-3.5-turbo` (`cl100k_base`)
> - `gpt-3.5-turbo-0301` (`cl100k_base`)

And [How to count tokens with tiktoken - OpenAI cookbook](https://github.com/openai/openai-cookbook/blob/main/examples/How_to_count_tokens_with_tiktoken.ipynb).